# Symfony: Form that embeds one object of Collection for OneToMany relation

Tags: php, forms, embed, one-to-many, symfony-2.8

I'm using Symfony 2.8 with Doctrine. And I have some trouble with form.

I think I understand how to create a form that embeds a single object or a collection of forms. But I want to create a form that embeds just one object of collection. Because the entities have OneToMany relation and I want to edit just one object of this relation in the same time.

Suppose that I want to create a page showing an article where an user can vote it.
Where can I put the user id so that an unique field can edit the vote attribute ?

Database

```
User:
    columns:
        id: integer
        username: string
        password: string
ArticleVote:
    columns:
        id: integer
        user_id: integer
        article_id: integer
        vote: boolean
Article:
    columns,
        id: integer
        title: string
        description: string
```

DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $article->setTitle('Title');
        $article->setDescription('Description');

        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

ArticleType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('articleVotes', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => ArticleVoteType::class));
    }
}
```

ArticleVoteType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

class ArticleVoteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('vote', ChoiceType::class, array(choices' => array('Yes' => true, 'No' => false,));
    }
}
```

default/index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.articleVotes.vote) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I know that in this case I can create the form in the controller directly with ArticleVoteType and ignor ArticleType but this is just an example.

Should I put an ArticleVote object in an $option array of createForm(ArticleType::class, $article, $option) method and don't add a CollectionType in ArticleType class ?
If yes, how should I write the ArticleType class ?

Comment: An other way is to add the ArticleVoteType directly in the ArticleType without CollectionType. But Symfony say me that the attribut is an Array collection and not a boolean because it's a votes attribut and not a vote.
So how can I invoke a findOneByUser($user) method ?